# How to adjust PlotHighlighting of version 13.3 to use custom labeling function?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, version-13.3

Consider the following dummy data.

```
data={{DateObject[{2022,11},"Month"],90.14},{DateObject[{2022,12},"Month"],98.47},{DateObject[{2023,1},"Month"],101.68},{DateObject[{2023,2},"Month"],97.87},{DateObject[{2023,3},"Month"],98.61},{DateObject[{2023,4},"Month"],102.71},{DateObject[{2023,5},"Month"],103.49},{DateObject[{2023,6},"Month"],100.01},{DateObject[{2023,7},"Month"],106.69},{DateObject[{2023,8},"Month"],100.94},{DateObject[{2023,9},"Month"],97.37},{DateObject[{2023,10},"Month"],99.38},{DateObject[{2023,11},"Month"],103.10},{DateObject[{2023,12},"Month"],94.38},{DateObject[{2024,1},"Month"],93.55},{DateObject[{2024,2},"Month"],86.48},{DateObject[{2024,3},"Month"],78.45},{DateObject[{2024,4},"Month"],71.26},{DateObject[{2024,5},"Month"],66.81},{DateObject[{2024,6},"Month"],75.38},{DateObject[{2024,7},"Month"],72.75},{DateObject[{2024,8},"Month"],63.43},{DateObject[{2024,9},"Month"],62.24},{DateObject[{2024,10},"Month"],65.01},{DateObject[{2024,11},"Month"],57.98},{DateObject[{2024,12},"Month"],49.03}};
```

Now plotting using the default setting:

```
ListPlot[data,Joined->True,PlotMarkers->"OpenMarkers",ScalingFunctions->{"Date",Automatic},ImageSize->Large]
```

I get bad formatting for labels:

[image]

But now if I add the `LabelingFunction` then the dynamic plot labeling disappears.

```
ListPlot[data,Joined->True,PlotMarkers->"OpenMarkers",ScalingFunctions->{"Date",Automatic},ImageSize->Large,
LabelingFunction->({DateObject[First@#1,"Month"],Quantity[Last@#1,"CanadianDollars"]}&)]
```

[image]

How do I get version 13.3 `PlotHighlighting` with more customization? Maybe some undocumented option or parameter to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
lf = {DateObject[#[[1, 1]], "Month"], Quantity[Last @ #1, "CanadianDollars"]} &; 

ListPlot[data, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Date", Automatic},
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotHighlighting -> {"XYLabel", <|LabelingFunction -> lf|>}]
```

[image]

**See:** [PlotHighlighting >> Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotHighlighting.html)

[image]

**Update:** ***"want points/line before ... to appear red and blue afterward"***

One way to get the desired result is to split the input data based on the desired threshold and use `PlotStyle` to style individual parts:

```
threshold = AbsoluteTime @ DateObject[{2023, 8}];

splitdata = Reverse @ Apply[{#, Prepend[Last @ #] @ #2} &] @
    SplitBy[data, AbsoluteTime @ First[#] <= threshold &];

marker = Graphics[{{White, Disk[{0, 0}]}, 
    AbsoluteThickness[2], Circle[{0, 0}]},  ImagePadding -> 2];

plotHighlighting = 
  {{"IndicatedPoint", <|"Style" -> AbsolutePointSize[12]|>}, 
   {"XYLabel", <|LabelingFunction -> lf|>}};

ListPlot[splitdata,
 PlotStyle -> { Blue, Red},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> {marker, .03},
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Date", Automatic},
 PlotHighlighting -> plotHighlighting,
 Filling -> Join[Thread[# -> {0, 150}] & /@ {1, 2}],
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[.07],
 GridLines -> {{threshold}, None}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

[image]

**Update 2:**

FWIW, a hack to modify highlighting of points based on the horizontoal coordinates:

```
epilogWithHighlighting = First @
  ListPlot[splitdata, 
    PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{}], 
    PlotStyle -> { Blue, Red}, 
    Joined -> False, 
    ScalingFunctions -> {"Date", Automatic},
    PlotHighlighting -> plotHighlighting];

ListPlot[data, 
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Date", Automatic}, 
 PlotHighlighting -> None,
 Epilog -> epilogWithHighlighting, 
 GridLines -> {{threshold}, None}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you @kglr. Can you also help me with one more thing. I want points/line before `DateObject[{2023,2}]` to appear red and blue afterward. I tried adding the option `ColorFunction->Function[{x,y},If[x<=AbsoluteTime@DateObject[{2023,2}],Red,Blue]]`. But this doesn't work.

Comment: @user13892, please see the update.